# Logic behind accessing dictionary values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Rookie here and I couldn't find a proper explanation for this.

We have a simple dict:

```py
a_dict = {'color': 'blue', 'fruit': 'apple', 'pet': 'dog'}
```

to loop through and access the values of this dict I have to call

```py
for key in a_dict:
    print(key, '->', a_dict[key])
```

I am saying about

```py
a_dict[key]
```

specifically. Why python use this convention? Where is a logic behind this? When I want to get values of a dictionary I should call it something like

```py
a_dict[value] or a_dict[values] etc
```

instead (thinking logically).

Could anyone explain it to make more sense please?

edit:

to be clear: why python use a_dict[key] to access dict VALUE instead of a_dict[value]. LOGICALLY.

Comment: Your question is unclear imo.

Comment: What is unclear exactly? Dicts are what they are meant to be, so...?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What is `a_dict[value] or a_dict[values] etc` supposed to be?

Comment: Dictionary, by definition, allows you accessing a value by the key. If you already have the value, you don't need a dict. Like, you know, why do I have search a phone book for John, not for 555-12-34?

Answer (score 2):

according to your question, I think you meant why python does not use index instead of key to reach values in the dict.

Please take note that there are 4 main data container in python, and each for its usage. (there are also other containers like counter and ...)

for example elements of list and tuple is reachable by their indices.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(a[0]) would print 1
```

but dictionary as its name shows, maps from some objects (keys in python terminology) to some other objects(values in python terminology). so we would call the key instead of index and the output would be the value.

```
a = { 'a':1 , 'b':2 }
print(a['a']) would print 1
```

I hope it makes it a bit more clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding some terminology around dictionaries:

In your example, your keys are `color`, `fruit`, and `pet`.
Your values are `blue`, `apple`, and `dog`.

In python, you access your values by calling `a_dict[key]`, for example `a_dict["color"]` will return `"blue"`.

If python instead used your suggested method of `a_dict[value]`, you would have to know what your value was before trying to access it, e.g. `a_dict["blue"]` would be needed to get `"blue"`, which makes very little sense.

As in Feras's answer, try reading up more on how dictionaries work [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Its because, a **dictionary** in python, *maps* the keys and values with a hash function internally in the memory.

Thus, to get the value, you've to pass in the `key`.

You can sort of think it like indices of the list vs the elements of the list, now to extract a particular element, you would use `lst[index]`; this is the same way dictionaries work; instead of passing in index you would've to pass in
the `key` you used in the dictionary, like `dict[key]`.

One more comparison is the dictionary (the one with words and meanings), in that the meanings are mapped to the words, now you would of course search for the `word` and not the `meaning` given to the word, directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a value wich you don't know if it exists or not in the dict, so the a_dict[key] is logic and correct